# Linkedin auth instead of native Webflow auth

Tags: linkedin-api, webflow, omniauth-linkedin

I'm hoping to build a site using Webflow where users will signup/login using Linkedin, instead of email/password.

Linkedin docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2

Webflow docs would suggest it's not possible:
"You can't remove the user email field, user password field, or the "Log in" button from the Log in form."
https://university.webflow.com/lesson/user-pages-overview?topics=users
However, I'm unclear if Linkedin is a suitable substitute, or if there's a workaround (ex: could I simply authenticate on a page that isn't /sign-up or /login?)